# getdatasourcerowindex nullreference after filter using gridview (Devexpress Winform)?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, devexpress, c#-3.0

I'm using gridview devexpress. After i use filter on that component, there is error nullreference. If i don't using filter. There isn't error on my code.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr;
            dr = GridView1.GetDataRow(GridView1.GetDataSourceRowIndex(i));
            MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());

        }
```

That is my code. Any solution to get datarow value from gridview after filter?

Comment: Which kind of filter are you using? Are you filtering your DataRow or the gridview? Are you using rowfilter or which filter?

Comment: @Sebi On gridview. At component gridview on devexpres,there is ShowautofilterRow, i use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that you are using RowCount. The DataSourceRowIndex is based on the index your underlying datasource holds. Thats not the same. If you are grouping or sorting the rowhandle of gridview is changing. And the RowCount only shows you how much rows are in the GridView. But this must not be equivalent to your datasourceindex.

try the following to get your datarow:

1.

```
foreach (DataRow row in ((DataTable)GridControl1.DataSource).Rows)
{
  //Here you can access your row via row variable
}
```

You have to know that the RowCount Property cant be used for accessing rows safely!

If you need further help dont hesitate for asking.

Comment: On gridview. At component gridview on devexpres,there is ShowautofilterRow, i use that. if i using filter on that component,  data on gridview always null if i use function getdatasourcerowindex .

Comment: Yes of course. You cant access GridView.RowCount and try to access on DataSource with that index. If you are using ShowAutoFilterRow = true the gridview will show an filterrow in top of gridview. This autofilterrow will be indexed by GridView.RowCount. But in your datasource wont be any row to this index. You dont have the filterrow in your datasource. Is my example working? Else post how you are creating the grid please.

Comment: @Sabi Thank's for your concern, but i have my code .this is my solution. ` DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)GridView1.GetRow(GridView1.GetVisibleRowHandle(i));
                MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

You must use [`BaseView.DataRowCount`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_DataRowCounttopic) property instead of [`BaseView.RowCount`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_RowCounttopic) property:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.DataRowCount; i++)
{
    DataRow dr;
    dr = GridView1.GetDataRow(GridView1.GetDataSourceRowIndex(i));
    MessageBox.Show(dr[i].ToString());
}
```